# Regarding using of external json file in angular 8 and convert into string array

Tags: json, angular, typescript, jexcelapi

im working in a project where are using a JExcel Grid,in that we are using a json file containing some data and we want to use it in one of the component and we also want to convert the json data into array of string so that we can use that data as a ROW data.

The json file,

```
[
    {

        "value":"Only laptop user"
    },
    {

        "value":"Only Dektop user"
    },
    {

            "value":"HVD with desktop"
    },
    {

        "value":"HVD with laptop"
    },
    {

        "value":"Dual assests laptop and desktop"
    }
]
```

The TS file,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as jexcel from 'jexcel';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {GetjsonService} from 'src/service/getjson.service';
import {User} from 'src/assets/user';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-staticdata',
  templateUrl: './staticdata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./staticdata.component.css']
})

export class StaticdataComponent implements OnInit {

  rowdata:any[];
  constructor(private jsonservice:GetjsonService) {
  //  console.log( jsonservice);
  }    

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsonservice. getvaluefromjson().then((rowdata) => (this.rowdata = rowdata));  
    console.log("Row data:"+this.rowdata);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jexcel(document.getElementById("spreadsheet") ,{
      // url:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AashiqinCode/Angular-JExcel/Aashiq/src/assets/user.json",

              columns: [
                { title: 'Value', type:'text',width:'300px' },

            ],
             minDimensions: [1,],
            contextMenu:function(){ return null;} ,//making the context menu as empty funciton
            // columnSorting:true,  
          });
        }

  selectedasset:String;
  asset = new FormControl();
  assetlist: string[] = ['Number of screens', 'Processing capacity above 8 GB ram', 'WFH Option', 'All Applications Whitelisted', 'Ethernet Cable', 'Stable Broadband connection'];


  // Adding a row on Grid
  gridrowadd(){}

}
```

You can see I've used an service to get the data by calling the function,

the service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from 'src/assets/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetjsonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    console.log("json service called");
  }
  getvaluefromjson(){
    return this.http
    .get<any>('assets/user.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then((res) => <User[]>res)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Data from json: "+data);
        return data;  });

}
}
```

The interface user.ts is,

```
export interface User{

    value?;
}
```

Despite using this i cant get the data,it says undefined,Please it will be usefull if you give the entire flow,thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably what you're looking for is [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Ofcourse,but i first want to get the JSON data from the external file saved assets folder in my json object.

Comment: You don't have to convert it to a promise. You could use `.pipe(take(1), map()` and convert the json to a string.

Comment: Your console log prints undefined because http.get is an asychronous call... try this:
`this.jsonservice. getvaluefromjson().then(rowdata=> { this.rowdata = rowdata ;   console.log("Row data:"+this.rowdata);})`

Comment: Ya David thanks,thats the solution,But how to convert the json to string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update service as

```
getvaluefromjson(){
    return this.http
    .get<any>('assets/user.json'); 
    // give valid path as assets/user.json might not work

}
```

in component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsonservice.getvaluefromjson().subscribe((res: User[]) => {
    this.data = res
    console.log(res);
    // now you can extract rows using for loop
    });  

  }
```

Comment: 'assets/user.json' =>is the correct path i think so

Comment: Hi Shlok,i got the json object ,i want to convert into array of strings can u please give the flow,thanks in advance

Comment: please give some example of what you have and what you need, I will update my answer